Labels are overprinted / ovelapped in Python ggplot
The country labels are overlapped when the graphic is generated. I need all labels be readable.
My code:
'''
import pandas as pd
import plotnine as pn

# Lê a base de dados
gapminder = pd.read_csv("gapminder.csv")

# Definindo a lista de regiões
west = ["Western Europe", "Northern Europe", "Southern Europe", "Northern America", "Australia and New Zealand"]

# Filtrando os dados e criando uma cópia
dat = (gapminder.query("year in [2010, 2015] and region in @west and life_expectancy.notna() and population > 10**7")).copy()

# Altera a coluna 'year' para 'life_expectancy_[YEAR]
dat['year'] = 'life_expectancy_' + dat['year'].astype(str)

# Cria uma nova base sendo uma coluna com o país, outras com os anos (o preenchimento será das expectativas de vida). reset_index() torna a coluna 'country', uma coluna de dados comum
dat_pivot = dat.pivot_table(index='country', columns='year', values='life_expectancy').reset_index()

# Calcula a média e a diferença
dat_pivot['average'] = (dat_pivot['life_expectancy_2010'] + dat_pivot['life_expectancy_2015']) / 2
dat_pivot['difference'] = dat_pivot['life_expectancy_2015'] - dat_pivot['life_expectancy_2010']

# Cria o gráfico
ggplot(dat_pivot, pn.aes('average', 'difference', label='country')) + pn.geom_point() + pn.geom_text(nudge_y = 0.02) + pn.geom_abline(linetype='dashed') + pn.xlab("Average of 2010 and 2015") + pn.ylab("Difference between 2015 and 2010")
'''

Result:

Important

The dataset is available in https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html
I have to use ggplot in Python

